# Can I read the Status Bar of IBM/HCL Notes using lotusscript?

Tags: lotus-notes, statusbar, lotusscript, hcl, hcl-notes

In order to determine if a typical condition has occurred, that is "Document has been modified or corrupted since signed!" message, which is printed by Notes itself on the Status Bar. So I want to read the status bar coz I already know that which line of code is likely to throw this warning on some occasion. Based on that I'll setup my code to work one way or the other. Thanks.

Comment: But if you already have LotusScript- Code that causes this error, why do you need to read statusbar? What is your REAL question / your REAL problem that you want to solve? This seams to be a [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: I mentioned in my question that this message is printed by Notes itself on the Status Bar, not my code. But what I know is the line of code upon whose execution Notes throws it. This is not an exception which i could get using ON ERROR, it rather seems to be a warning written by Notes on the status bar. My question is simple "Is there a way to read the status bar content?".

Comment: The only way is to set notes.ini LogStatusBar=1 and then read it from console.log or log.nsf

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get the contents of the statusbar in LotusScript or @Formula.

BUT: You can make sure, that whatever appears in the statusbar is written to log.nsf and / or console.log in IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT ... from there you can check with LotusScript. Just set the notes.ini- Parameter

LogStatusBar=1

on the client executing your code, then every output in the statusbar will be written to above mentioned two places and can be read from there.